# SignalR Self-Host vs IIS performance and fault tolerance

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, signalr, self-hosting

Recently I deployed a production SignalR chat application for our company. However I learned the signalr api/several other things while writing it. So it isn't quite as well written as I would like. So I am going to re-write it with my new found knowledge. However I would like to take this opportunity to consider self host instead of IIS.

I have :

1. ASP.Net MVC 5 Service on IIS(The server has a controller for
   uploading files.)
2. 2 Web Client(hosted on a separate website from the server)
3. Desktop Client

My main reason for wanting self host is to abstract all the parts out to separate everything for ease of maintainability and ease of writability.

**But not using IIS means each request wouldn't grab from a thread pool and any errors would cause the server to crash all together right?**

**Would having all my hub code be async Tasks be enough to handle say 1000 connected clients? Not all of these would be actively chatting, but anyone browsing our site would have to be connected.**

My future solution would like :

1. SignalR Server
2. WebApi project on IIS or self hosted for uploading files
3. Desktop Client
4. Web Client

Comment: There are great blog post comparing the performance in both cases, so why not search?

Comment: @lex_li I have.  But nothing explicitly comparing only vague comparisons, hence where I got fault tolerance and lack of thread pool from